# Difference between "überfallen" and "attackieren"

Tags: meaning

I would like to know what difference is there between *überfallen and attackieren*. 
Is it correct to think that **überfallen** could be a person who attacks another one, while **attackieren** could be an army or a state attacking another one? 
In which contexts is one better than the other one? Can they be synonym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Überfall* could be translated to *raid* or *hold-up*. It can be a kind of break-in. In most cases an *Überfall* is done to steal something. It can be used as *Banküberfall* which means *bank hold-up*. If someone threatens a person (or uses violence) and want something valuable, that could also be considered a *Überfall*. 
 This is a very similar word to *Raub*, which also means theft with use of violence. Sometimes these words get mixed up to *Raubüberfall*. In most cases a *Raubüberfall* indicates more violence than an *Überfall*. In most cases *überfallen* is something very fast. Therefore it could also be used to say, that an attack was very fast and surprising. But that's rather unusual.

*Attackieren* simply means *to attack*. This word does not include that a attack is made because of profit. It could also be done because of revenge or fun or some other reason. Not only states, but also persons can attack each other. The goal of this kind of attack is to harm somebody/something.

Answer (score 1):

*Attackieren* puts emphasis on violence. You can attack someone verbally or physically.

*Überfallen* has a few meanings with subtle differences. All of them have in common that it's about a sudden, unexpected "attack" (don't know a better term here).
First, there's robbery. Robbery is possible without violence. Second, you suddenly confront someone with something. That does (usually) not include any form of violence. And third, there's a military attack, which most like include *violence*.

Answer (score 0):

Synonym to some extend I think

Both would work in a military context I think.

In everyday conversations *attackieren* would be one person attacking/insulting another person. With words or physically.

*überfallen* always is a physical thing. A raid, a military engagement that was not to be expected at that point in time or in that form.

In personal conflicts *Attackieren* is used when it is an attack on someones life or at least physical integrity whereas *überfallen* is used to describe an action to "gather something" - steal personal property/money - so it is not against a person but against the belongings.

Comment: *Überfallen* is not necessarily a physical thing. [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/überfallen): [3] übertragen: unvorbereitet mit etwas konfrontieren –
[4] übertragen: von Gefühlen ergriffen werden

Comment: OK, fine with that. Überfallen can be used in that kind of informal way. Didn't think of that.